# Got UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "noNamespaceSchemaLocation" during run "allure serve {projectpath}\target\surefire-reports"

Tags: testng, allure

When try to use Allure to generate testing report with command "**allure serve {projectpath}\target\surefire-reports**", it's throw exception as below:

```
Could not read xml result {projectpath}\target\surefire-reports\TEST-TestSuite.xml: {}
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "noNamespaceSchemaLocation" (class ru.yandex.qatools.allure.model.TestSuiteResult), not marked as ignorable (8 known properties: "start", "title", "name", "description", "labels", "stop", "version", "test-cases"])
 at [Source: (sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream); line: 2, column: 263] (through reference chain: ru.yandex.qatools.allure.model.TestSuiteResult["noNamespaceSchemaLocation"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:823)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1153)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1589)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1567)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:294)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3070)
        at io.qameta.allure.allure1.Allure1Plugin.readXmlTestSuiteFile(Allure1Plugin.java:460)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
        at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
        at io.qameta.allure.allure1.Allure1Plugin.readResults(Allure1Plugin.java:136)
        at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.lambda$readResults$0(ReportGenerator.java:47)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.readResults(ReportGenerator.java:47)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
        at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:69)
        at io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:58)
        at io.qameta.allure.Commands.generate(Commands.java:105)
        at io.qameta.allure.Commands.serve(Commands.java:130)
        at io.qameta.allure.CommandLine.run(CommandLine.java:159)
        at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
        at io.qameta.allure.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:88)
```

These exception also can be seen at IDEA IDE with file {projectpath}\target\surefire-reports\TEST-TestSuite.xml, and the related property like:

```
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/xsd/surefire-test-report.xsd"
```

What's the problem here? Really need help, thanks.

Comment: please do not take screenshot and elaborate

Comment: OK, got it and removed.